# Why import rajawali.*; cannot be resolved! Am i doing something wrong?

Tags: android, opengl-es, rajawali

i need to touch 3d objects in my android. And most of people i asked in forum, they suggesting me to use Rajawali as the framework. [I am using **Android Studio**]

I look into so many tutorial but i always stuck here:

```
import rajawali.*;
```

**it shows cannot be resolved.**

Then I've downloaded the source code from here [MasDennis/Rajawali](https://github.com/Rajawali/Rajawali/tree/master/rajawali/src/main/res/raw) hoping it could give me a clear view of my mistakes. But i cant even test it / played it in the android studio. (Run test the app in my phone).

Please. Im really trying to figure out. and im stuck just here for almost a week now. If this fix, i can continue with my program. Thanks for the help.

**P/s:** I forgot to mention this before. I did add the codes in the build gradle. Im following exactly from [this tutorial](http://www.clintonmedbery.com/?p=59*/). Im successfully adding the .obj file. However, i cannot continue to any functions that requires me to **import rajawali.*;**

Comment: The import statement in the tutorial says `import org.rajawali3d.renderer.RajawaliRenderer;`. Why are you doing `import rajawali.*`

Comment: @Prerak im doing object picking. It requires me to import rajawali.BaseObject3D; import rajawali.Object3D; and many more from the import rajawali.*;. Or perhaps, i dont have to use object picking if i want to touch the object? Is that so?

Comment: For `Object3D` its `import org.rajawali3d.Object3D;`